# Chartboost Integration

Tags: ads, chartboost

I have an app in Xcode that has no ads built in and want to add Chartboost. I downloaded the SDK but am stuck. I have the latest chartboost SDK and when I add it to xcode, I get an issue that says Cannot initialize a parameter of type `id<ChartboostDelegate' with an Ivalue of type 'AppController*`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to add chartboostDelegate to the AppController interface.
It should look something like this:

```
@interface AppController : NSObject <UIAccelerometerDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate,
UITextFieldDelegate,UIApplicationDelegate, ChartboostDelegate>
```

You should also have this at the top: #import "Chartboost.h"

Answer (score 0):

Just put it on the top of you appDelegate.m :

```
#import <Chartboost/Chartboost.h>
#import <Chartboost/CBNewsfeed.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate () <ChartboostDelegate, CBNewsfeedDelegate>
@end
```

Enjoy !